# Android EditText align right no work properly

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, gravity

This is my code:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_height"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
```

I want the text go from right, so I add this code: `android:gravity="right"`.

The problem is that the cursor always remain at right.
I Attaching screen shots:

With gravity right  - 
[image]
[image]

Without gravity right - 
[image]
[image]

Actually I want it will be like the first image and the last image.

Any help?

Comment: Do you solve this problem? If yes please let me know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Android offers support for right-to-left languages since Android 4.2. See [this article on the Android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html).

> With a few simple changes, your app will be automatically mirrored 
>       when the user switches the system language to a right-to-left script 
>       (such as Arabic, Hebrew, or Persian).
>
> To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following changes to your app:
>
> Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.
>   Specifically, add android:supportsRtl="true" to the  element in your manifest file.
>
> Change all of your app's "left/right" layout properties to new "start/end" equivalents.
>   If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example, android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
>   If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused due to the devices or emulators keyboard `Locale`, If it is set to a language that is not right to left it could override (someone correct me if I'm wrong here).